# Get current date with fixed time string - moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Consider that the date is 2021 may 19, I need to get the string as **2021-05-19T23:59:00.000Z**

I tried moment().format() but it is returning the current datetime string.

I need the time in the formatString to be **23:59** so that the total string becomes 2021-05-19T23:59:00.000Z

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [endOf](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/):

```
moment().endOf('day')
```

and the use `format` in order to get the exact format you need:

```js
let t1 = new moment();
console.log(t1.format());

let t2 = t1.endOf('day');
console.log(t2.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `moment().endOf("day").format()`.

```js
console.log(moment().endOf("day").format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

You can use plain javascript to do the same.

```
var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:00.000[Z]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method endOf() from moment.js :

```
moment().endOf('day').format()
```

To print the time in your local time, try using toString().

```
let now = moment();
console.log('end : ' + now.endOf('day').toString());
```